# Custom Json.NET float formatting

Tags: c#, json, serialization, formatting

I'm using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for object serialization. I have a lot of float values so my Json string get's very big. I don't need high precision so I was wondering if you could set up a custom float format. For example rounding to 2 decimals.

```
3.14159265359 => 3.14
```

The only thing I figured out was a `DateFormatHandling` using the `JsonSerializerSettings`. but nothing with floats.

Comment: Why don't you round your numbers before serializing?

Comment: As Stefano said, just round the numbers using `Math.Round(..)` before serializing

Comment: The reason why I'm not rounding always is that these values are calculated with higher performance on server side, and client side only needs lower precision since these values are only some markers for interpolations. So the basic idea was just to reduce the amount of traffic being send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to code your own custom type converter. See here for an example of a custom converter:

[How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)

You simply need to adapt it to round up when you write out your float value.

Comment: That would be a whole lot of work when the goal is to round some numbers.

Comment: @JordyLangen Oh I don't argue with you there. But it is a solution.